# Returning functions that check for equality/ordinal comparison for any valid type parameter

Tags: scala, operators, typeclass, implicit

I'm not very experienced with using Scala and I think I'm missing something when it comes to implicits. I'm essentially trying to take an enumerated argument that represents a certain logical operator (e.g. representing greater than '>' as the enumerated value Greater) and return a function that will apply that operator to a left and right operand and return the boolean result.

So, for example, if I had something like the following:
`val gt = LogicalOperator[Int](Greater)`

then `gt(2, 1)` would return `True`. I'd also like this to work for the `==` and `!=` operators as well but additionally extended to iterables (e.g. `eq(List(1,2,3), List(1,2,3))` returns `True`).

So basically I want to be able to generate comparative functions for a generic type parameter of `Ordering` or `Iterable` and be able to pass the function around to other methods and/or objects. I've been trying to use Typeclasses with implicits but I'm running into issues with using traits such as `Ordering` as type parameters.

Here is basically what I have so far. Started with the enumerated operators:

```
object LogicalOperation extends Enumeration {
  type LogicalOperation = Value
  val Greater, GreaterEqual, Less, LessEqual, Equal, NotEqual = Value

  def fromName(s: String): Value = values.find(_.toString == s).get
}
```

Then trying to create some implicit operator factories:

```
sealed trait OperatorFactory[T] {
  def apply(operation: LogicalOperation): (T, T) => Boolean
}

object OperatorFactory {
  implicit class OrderedOperator[T: Ordering](operation: LogicalOperation)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]) extends OperatorFactory[T] {
    def apply(operation: LogicalOperation): (T, T) => Boolean = {
      operation match {
        case Greater => ord.gt
        case GreaterEqual => ord.gteq
        case Less => ord.lt
        case LessEqual => ord.lteq
        case Equal => ord.equiv
        case NotEqual => (l: T, r: T) => !ord.equiv(l, r)
      }
    }
  }


  implicit class IterableOperator[Iterable](operation: LogicalOperation) extends OperatorFactory[Iterable] {
    def apply(operation: LogicalOperation): (Iterable, Iterable) => Boolean = {
      operation match {
        case Equal => (l: Iterable, r: Iterable) => l.equals(r)
        case NotEqual => (l: Iterable, r: Iterable) => !l.equals(r)
        case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Logical operation ${operation} not applicable for Iterables.")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then creating an operator object to implicitly select the right factory and return the operator function (I think this is part of what is not correct):

```
object LogicalOperator {
  
  implicit def OrderedOperator[T: Ordering](operation: LogicalOperation) = OperatorFactory.OrderedOperator[T](operation)
  implicit def IterOperator[Iterable](operation: LogicalOperation) = OperatorFactory.IterableOperator[Iterable](operation)

  def apply[T](operation: LogicalOperation)(implicit operatorFactory: OperatorFactory[T]): (T, T) => Boolean = {
    operatorFactory.apply(operation)
  }
}
```

Now, I'm running into a couple of compile errors. If I try to instantiate one of these operator functions as follows:

```
val gt = LogicalOperator[Int](Greater)
```

I get basically the following error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter operatorFactory: OperatorFactory[Int]
```

Edit: [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7662670/tim)'s answer helped correct this issues:
<strike>If I remove that line of code, then I get errors on the implicit classes of the OperatorFactory:</strike>

```
class OrderedOperator needs to be abstract, since method apply in trait OperatorFactory of type [T](operation: LogicalOperation.LogicalOperation)(T, T) => Boolean is not defined
```

So I think there are issues both with how I'm trying to implicitly instantiate the OperatorFactory and with how the abstract methods for the operator factory are implemented.

I'm also wondering if there is just a simpler way to instantiate and pass around these comparative functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
sealed trait OperatorFactory[T] {
  def apply[T](operation: LogicalOperation): (T, T) => Boolean
}
```

This code has two type parameters called `T`. The first is the type parameter of the `trait`, and the second is the type parameter of `apply`. You probably want to use the same type in both places, so remove the type parameter from `apply`:

```
sealed trait OperatorFactory[T] {
  def apply(operation: LogicalOperation): (T, T) => Boolean
}
```

Enabling the compiler option `-Xlint:type-parameter-shadow` should generate a warning for this.

Comment: Yes thank you, this solves the issue with the apply method. I also realized that I can cut out all of the implicit method definitions for each comparison function which simplifies this considerably. I've updated my original comment to reflect the changes. Still running into the 'could not find implicit value for the parameter'.